# Defaulting to user input using a lambda when parameter is not explicitly passed

Tags: c++, function, default-arguments

I wrote the following code ([Still wondering about its uses...](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/242702/how-effective-is-it-to-default-to-user-input-in-c-function-parameters)) to default to user input if the parameter is not passed.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>

unsigned getInput() {
    unsigned input;
    std::cin >> input;
    return input;
}

void foo(unsigned number = getInput()) {
    std::cout << number << "\n";
}

int main() {
    foo(1); //prints 1
    foo();  //defaults to user input    
    return 0;
}
```

---

What I wanted to ask was, is there any way we can convert the `getInput()` function to a lambda?
Something on the lines of

```
void foo(unsigned number = { []() {unsigned num = 0; std::cin >> num; return num; } }) {
    std::cout << number << "\n";
}
```

Also, how does one achieve similar functionality in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939282/achieve-the-user-input-for-default-parameter-functionality-in-python)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a lambda.  What you need to do is call the lambda after you define it like

```
void foo(unsigned number = []() {unsigned num = 0; std::cin >> num; return num; }()) 
//                         ^                   define lambda                    ^^^
//                                                               call lambda_____|
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but you are missing the call to the lambda:

```
void foo(unsigned number = [] {
               unsigned num = 0; 
               std::cin >> num; 
               return num; 
              }()   // <- call here
        ) 
{
    std::cout << number << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, is `[]()` not always necessary when defining a lambda? I see you haven't used the parenthesis after `[]`

Comment: That's correct. The `()` after `[]` is optional in a lambda that takes no arguments.