# Achieve the user input for default parameter functionality in python

Tags: python, function, default-arguments

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61938875/defaulting-to-user-input-using-a-lambda-when-parameter-is-not-explicitly-passed) is a `C++` code I wrote to default to user input when arguments are not provided explicitly.
I have been learning `Python-3.7` for the past week and am trying to achieve a similar functionality.

This is the code I tried:

```
def foo(number = int(input())):
    print(number)

foo(2)  #defaults to user input but prints the passed parameter and ignores the input
foo()   #defaults to user input and prints user input
```

---

This code works, but not quite as intended. You see, when I pass an argument to `foo()`, it prints the argument, and when I don't pass any, it prints the user input. The problem is, it asks for user input even when an argument has been passed, like `foo(2)`, and then ignores the user input. How do I change it to work as intended (as in it should not ask for user input when an argument has been passed)

Comment: Don't put function calls like `input()` or `list()` **in the function declaration line** when you define default arg values, that doesn't work as intended. Related: [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int(input())` is executed *when the function is defined*. What you should do is use a default like `None`, then do `number = int(input())` if needed:

```
def foo(number=None):
    if number is None:
         number = int(input())
    print(number)
```